# C# EF core bulk insert gives error The instance of entity type 'entity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I want to insert a set of records in a single transaction in EF Core. I'm new to EF Core. But I get the following exception when adding the entity at the 2nd iteration of the loop:

> The instance of entity type 'Entity' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

I've used unit of work and repository pattern.

This is the Create code block

```
if (_trmshedulePlan.Count > 0)
{
      foreach (var item in _trmshedulePlan)
      {
          _trmShedulePlanRepository.Create(item);
      }

      _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

And this is my create method:

```
public void Create(T entity)
{
    this.TRMContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;
    this.TRMContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
}
```

I've done following changes to my context create service, but still getting above error.

```
 services.AddDbContext<OnlineFeedbackContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TRMDatabase")).UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking));
 services.AddScoped<OnlineFeedbackContext>();
```

Comment: It is saying that two of the items you added have the same value in the property `Id` and that the property is a primary key. Fix the duplicated value in the source data.

Comment: This code `this.TRMContext.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Detached;` may introduce problem.